# Why am I getting the wrong path when I auto import Typescript class in IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

If I am in my IntelliJ and I try to command space to auto import an Typescript class I get the full path (`import {Http} from "../../../../node_modules/@angular/http/src/http";`) when I would expect the shorter on (`import {Http} from "@angular/http"`)

This worked at one point but I can't figure out what setting got rejiggered. Anyone have an idea? I am on 2017.1

Comment: Am having the same issue. Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope not yet good luck I will be interested in an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have the exclude the node_modules in the project settings, only not excluded modules are used for auto import. Auto import get the packages from your  `package.json` file. Look at the comments here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25643#tab=Comments

Answer (score 1):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports**, try enabling `Use paths relative to tsconfig.json`. When this checkbox is selected, import paths are calculated relative to the "baseUrl" specified in tsconfig; if this option is omitted, it's considered to be equal to a directory where tsconfig.json is located.